# C++ MFC Appeding text to edit control crashes the program

Tags: c++, mfc

[image: This is the disassembly of the program at runtime when exception occurs]Class in test.h:

```
class CHelixV3Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
   DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CHelixV3Dlg);
friend class CHelixV3DlgAutoProxy;

// Construction
public:
   CHelixV3Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
   enum { IDD = IDD_HELIXV3_DIALOG };


// Implementation
protected:
   CHelixV3DlgAutoProxy* m_pAutoProxy;
   HICON m_hIcon;
public:
   DWORD WINAPI loop(LPVOID); //thread identifier
   void AppendText(CEdit &edit, LPCTSTR pszText);
};
```

I have a method defined like so, which is supposed to print a string to editbox, which normally works (in test.cpp):

```
void TestDlg::AppendText(CEdit &edit, LPCWSTR pszText)
{
   // get the initial text length
   int nLength = edit.GetWindowTextLength();
   // put the selection at the end of text
   edit.SetSel(nLength, nLength);
   // replace the selection
   edit.ReplaceSel(pszText);
 }
```

Then here is my thread, which listens for key presses(test.cpp)

```
 DWORD WINAPI TestDlg::KeyThread(LPVOID PARAMS)
 {
    TestDlg* Testdlg;
    while (1)
    {
       Sleep(1);
       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
       {
           Enabled = !Enabled;
           if (Enabled) {
            CEdit* log = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
            log->AppendText(*log, "test"); //causes a crash
       }
    }
   return 0;
  }
```

Dialog initialization, where the "loop" thread is created:

```
BOOL CHelixV3Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
TestDlg* Testdlg;
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

//creates the thread->
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &Testdlg->KeyThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

/* IGNORE THIS */
CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
if (pSysMenu != NULL)
{
    BOOL bNameValid;
    CString strAboutMenu;
    bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
    {
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
    }
}

// Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
//  when the application's main window is not a dialog
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

// TODO: Add extra initialization here

return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

**So, the program compiles, but when it's running and i press F1, it crashes.**

Comment: `CEdit* log = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);`  You didn't check to see if `log` is a valid pointer after that statement is executed.  You just assumed it was ok to use.  Secondly, if you're going to write all of this code, it would make it worth your while to use the debugger to diagnose these issues.

Comment: In `CHelixV3Dlg::OnInitDialog()` you have `TestDlg* Testdlg;` which means `Testdlg` will be an unitialized pointer and `&Testdlg->KeyThread` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: But How to fix it? I've been struggling with this for a day...

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems in your code. The uninitialized `Testdlg` pointer has been already pointed by others.

Here is another one:

```
log->AppendText(*log, "test");
```

I'm sure you want to say:

```
Testdlg->AppendText(*log, "test");
```

However, that won't work, because this is on a worker thread. What you have to do is post/send a message from the worker thread to the queue of the main thread (that created your test dialog window). In the handler for the message, you can actually call your `AppendText` method.

Here is how you do that (**notice that I've typed all this in the browser so it may contain errors**):

In the header (TestDlg.h) declare a handler:

```
LRESULT OnMessageFromWorker(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lPARAM);
```

In the source file (TestDlg.cpp):

Define your message:

```
#define MY_WORKER_THREAD_MSG   WM_APP + 123
```

Add an entry for the message in the message map

```
ON_MESSAGE(MY_WORKER_THREAD_MSG, &TestDlg::OnMessageFromWorker)
```

Send the message from the worker thread:

```
 DWORD WINAPI TestDlg::KeyThread(LPVOID PARAMS)
 {
    HWND dlgWnd = (HWND)PARAMS;
    while (1)
    {
       Sleep(1);
       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
       {
           Enabled = !Enabled;
           if (Enabled) 
           {
               CString* msg = new CString("test");
               PostMessage(dlgWnd, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(msg));
           }
       }
    }
   return 0;
  }
```

Notice that in this example you need to pass the `HWND` of the dialog window, not the `this` pointer to the thread function. In other words:

```
CreateThread(nullptr, nullptr, &Testdlg->KeyThread, this->GetSafeHwnd(), nullptr, nullptr);
```

Handle the message:

```
LRESULT TestDlg::OnMessageFromWorker(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lPARAM)
{
   CString* msg = reinterpret_cast<CString*>(lPARAM);
   CEdit* log = (CEdit*)TestDlg->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
   AppendText(*log, *msg);
   delete msg; // you must delete the object

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you should define TestDlg::Thread as a static member function.  When you call CreateThread, the fourth argument should be 'this'.

In your header file (TestDlg.h or whatever):

```
static DWORD WINAPI TestDlg::KeyThread(LPVOID PARAMS);
```

In OnInitDialog:

//creates the thread->

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &Testdlg->KeyThread, this, NULL, NULL);


DWORD WINAPI TestDlg::KeyThread(LPVOID PARAMS)
 {
    TestDlg* Testdlg = (TestDlg*) PARAMS;
    while (1)
    {
       Sleep(1);
       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
       {
           Enabled = !Enabled;
           if (Enabled) {
            CEdit* log = (CEdit*)TestDlg->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
            log->AppendText(*log, "test"); //causes a crash
       }
    }
   return 0;
  }
```

It still may not work because the CWnd pointers may only be valid in the main thread.  YMMV

Comment: Uhm... **all** `HWND`s have thread affinity, and must not be modified from any other thread than the owning thread. The `CWnd` pointers are valid in every thread. Haven't we been through this before?